# Why are some red items legal and others illegal?

Tags: rebel-galaxy-outlaw

As you can see in the picture below, some items are red but Illegal (blue arrow) and some items are also red but not marked as Illegal (green arrow).

[image]

So, why are the green arrows marked as red but not marked as Illegal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the red items are categorized contraband, which is illegal and will get you in trouble with the police if they scan your ship and find any.

*However*...
Not all stations consider all types of contraband illegal. You may buy/sell contraband that is not illegal (your green arrows in the screenshot) at a particular station.
You cannot take any action with contraband that is illegal (other than taking it elsewhere that it).

Apparently it is the type of government that determines whether or not a certain type of contraband is illegal, according to [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/RebelGalaxy/comments/c4u2h7/are_you_new_and_dont_know_where_to_sell_contraband/). This post includes a small chart of which governments accept which contraband, although it is not complete unfortunately... It also seems to be in regards to Rebel Galaxy (not Outlaw), but the concept generally appies to both games.

Here's the chart from the above mentioned post:

[image: contraband chart]

Comment: I believe that chart is not from outlaw. But after observing the game, the idea still applies.

Comment: @vianna77 - That is likely. It actually seems really hard to find details on Outlaw. The reddit post does seem to apply to both though, since the economy systems seem really similar (and the subreddit is for both games).

Comment: Yep, I noticed that. All my questions here were posted there too. Not many people are playing this game since it is Epic exclusive.

Comment: @vianna77 - Yeah, I played RG on PS4 and don't do a whole lot of PC gaming. Though it sounds like RGO is eventually coming to PS4/Switch/XB1, so I'll definitely have to pick that up. I thought RG was tons of fun, although I never actually finished it.